# CocoonJS + Crafty compatibility

Tags: html, craftyjs, cocoonjs

I just have a simple question: has anyone tried deploying a HTML5 game built on Crafty Game Engine (CraftyJS earlier) into a CocoonJS container?

If so, what is your experience? How does it perform? Any issues?

Comment: I have created a issue and will try getting Crafty.js running on CocoonJS https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/issues/576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an usable port and it works great! I'm updating my advances in https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/craftyjs/2Ftv0kYGbXg where I'm posting my prototypes. I think in 1 or 2 weeks I will finish this crafty version.

Of course, Crafty won't work out of the box in CocoonJS for now (at least the official version). But after I finish, the cocoon enabled craftyjs will be available for anyone to download and test, and maybe I can get starwed's attention to make an integrated version.

My experience with the hacked port: The performance is great! CraftyJS is so low level, it's almost like common JS anyway, so no speed concerns around that if you know what your'e doing. I think some work has to be done in the multi touch support though.